# Strange black bar in middle of UITextField in landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, swift5

I have tried to debug it via view debugger but still not able to detect the reason for that.

TextField has below custom class if maybe that has some hidden issue

```
class ChatTextField: UITextField {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initNib()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initNib()
    }

    func initNib() {

        self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Send a message to Kael",
                                                        attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.1879999936, green: 0.1979999989, blue: 0.2930000126, alpha: 1)])
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
        self.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3059999943, green: 0.5329999924, blue: 0.5490000248, alpha: 1)

        self.addInnerShadow(onSide: .all, shadowColor: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2), shadowSize: 10, cornerRadius: 15, shadowOpacity: 0.8)
    }
    let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 30)

     override open func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
     }

     override open func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
     }

     override open func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
     }
}
```

[image: Strange bklack bar in middle of UITextField]

[image: View debugger]

[image: Storyboard UI]

Comment: Can you please share your UI or Storyboard for this screen?

Comment: @HardikS This what you are asking for?

Comment: why you have written this line `addInnerShadow` in `initNib()`?

Comment: Maybe your inner shadow code causes a black bar in the `UITextField`?

Comment: Glad to help you. I have written my answer. You can mark it as accepted and also upvoted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling a method to give inner shadow from the method of `initNib()` of `UITextField` extension.

You will have to modify the shadow method by setting the different `offset` according to portrait and landscape mode.

Try to remove your shadow method which will apply shadow to textfield and then check it is working properly or not.